# How to add exe as reference in my web application

Tags: .net

I have created an exe with some methods in it (ref example exe below).

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Text;  

namespace SampleRef  
{  
  public class Program  
  {  
  static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
    }  
  }  
  public class Sample  
  {    
   public Sample(int count)  
    {

    }

    public string SampleString(int InputValue)
    {
      //Do something
       return "<the result>";
    }
  }  
}
```

I want to add reference this exe into my web application to call (SampleString) methods in side the exe. Is it possible in .net and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Generally, you would do this as an assembly and not as an .EXE.  Any particular reason for your choice of the latter?

Comment: Yes. I have already developed an exe with some methods. Now I am developing a web application, and it needs to use some methods inside the exe. Adding exe is allowed in VS2005. But I can't access the namespace, classes in it. Alternatively any other way for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - just add it as if it were a class library. Visual Studio has supported this since 2005.

EDIT: Okay, it sounds like ASP.NET may not like .exe assemblies :(

In that case I suggest you extract the code from your current executable and put it into a class library. You may find it easier to change the *whole* of your normal application into a DLL - and just add another executable project which does nothing but call into the DLL to start the "application". That shouldn't be the end-point of your code, but it's an easy way to get up and running.

Comment: Hi Jon, I have added with Add reference thro VS2005. But in web app, the namespace SampleRef is available.

Comment: @Selva TS: It certainly should be... what happens if you add a `using SampleRef;` statement in your code?

Comment: @Selva: What exact compiler error? Do you see the same error if you add a reference to a normal class library?

Comment: Hi Jon, I got this compiler error when adding reference the exe.(Actually reference added but not accessible in code) - "The type or namespace name 'SampleRef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @Selva: Okay - and what happens if you just add a reference to a class library (for testing purposes)?

Comment: When adding a class library all the methods are available for use. But adding exe makes only problem.

Comment: @Selva TS: Okay... maybe it's something weird that ASP.NET's doing... it would certainly be fine from a normal application :(

Comment: Hi Jon thanks.. Yes.. I have checked with console application as well as windows application. It works fine. But in ASP.Net application only it makes problem.

Comment: @Selva: In that case, I'm afraid I don't know... will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely can add and use a reference to an exe in exactly the same way that you would a dll (.net 4 at least).

I think the missing assembly message is probably a red herring, if you've added a reference successfully and get this message when you try to use it, I've always found this is due to targeting different versions of framework (usually the Client Profile version being defaulted).

Comment: I had the same problem and selecting the same framework version in both projects (exe and the one references the exe) solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Final compiled output in .Net is called Assemblies and EXEs are no different in this case. It's just that they carry a special header that identify them as executables with program entry points and normal compiled dll assemblies don't have this, but both are assemblies and you can add assemblies as reference in any .net project you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Just go to the `Project` menu, select `Add Reference` change to the `Browse` tab and find and select the executable.